# Delay send emails using MailMessage and SmtpClient or MessageQueue

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, message-queue

I am using `SmtpClient` and `MailMessage` to send emails from `ASP.Net` code.
I want to be able to **delay** the delivery of emails based on business logic. 
I will be able to generate a `DateTime` object about when the email should actually be delivered.

I am aware that I can create a **Windows Service** to schedule email delivery using `Sql Server` database as an email storage. But I do not want to deploy an extra service on the hosting server.

I am also aware that I can create a `SQL Server` job to achieve this, but I would not like to, until and unless, this cannot be achieved using pure `ASP.NET`

A point to note is that, my code checks whether `MSMQ` is enabled on the server. If it is, `MessageQueue` class is used for email delivery. So any pointers on achieving this using queues will be helpful.

By the way, the solution should work in both cases (i.e. with `SmtpClient` as well as `MessageQueue`.

I have already reviewed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5161247/c-net-best-way-to-queue-emails-with-attachments-for-sending) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4973976/good-examples-of-applications-using-message-queues) questions and its accepted answers. I do not want to use 3rd party products until and unless this cannot be achieved using pure `ASP.NET`

P.S. .Net Framework version : 3.5, IIS 7 and Sql Server 2008 should be the environment.

Comment: You could simply add some application logic to send all pending messages every X minutes. You can hook up a timer in the Application_Start event. Just make sure you're asp.net application isn't shut down if there are no visitors for X minutes.

Comment: @CodingBarfield : It would be great if you can show some sample code ? I suspect that the efforts to `make sure asp.net application isn't shut down if there are no visitors for X minutes` is high. So can you compose an answer showing your method of implementation for me to verify ?

Comment: @AYKSorry  I haven't worked with asp.net enough recently to give a guaranteed working solution. It might be a trivial IIS switch or something hard to do but I can't give any guarantees.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research and clarifications from client, it was decided that I should create a long running background thread, which will handle sending of emails at pre-defined times and need not bother about whether the application pool has been shut down due to inactivity.

Answer (score 1):

Some information about keeping a timer running in asp.net including a great comment about an always on scenario:

[Start timer on web application start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3000781/start-timer-on-web-application-start)

You can use the following to keep asp.net from shutting down:

[Can you prevent your ASP.NET application from shutting down?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1306380/can-you-prevent-your-asp-net-application-from-shutting-down)

You can simply use the timer to check a database and send all pending mail.